# SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

NET so I clone a project on github and build it in my local machine. I got this error

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
> while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
> found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
> and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to
> SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Please help me with it

Comment: Please tell us what part of the error message you're having trouble with.

Comment: what s the sql connection string ?

Comment: is it local sql or are you trying to connect to remote sql ?

Comment: Sounds like your program cannot connect to sql server. Do you have one running and does the connection string match your settings? Cloning random projects might mean you need to read the docs and have stuff setup correctly